# Access GPIO pins on pandaboard running ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, kernel

The trouble I'm having is that the error message shows that the kernel does not support gpio. So, what should I do to make the kernel support gpio?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. It could eventually help people to provide a good answer if you provide the error message and other relevant information you know of.

Comment: Did you follow these steps already? I followed the introduction guide on pandaboard.org and landed there: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Pre-built_Binaries_Guide